# Matlab function with symsum works in CommandWindow but not when I run it from m-file

Tags: matlab, variables, sum, double

I need an array of zeros to preallocate my `folds` variable so it doesn't change size every iteration, thus being slow. My `folds` array should have this much elements: 
[image]
where k is input argument.So I first tried

```
>> syms n;
>> zeros(1,symsum(2^n, n, 0, k-1))
```

in Command Window and got error ,

```
Error using zeros
Size inputs must be numeric.
```

so i added double():
`>> zeros(1,double(symsum(2^n, n, 0, k-1)))`
and  it worked in Command Window. For k=3 i got an array of 7 zeros, just like wanted. Then I do the same in my M-file

```
function dragonCurve(k)
   syms n;
   folds = zeros(1,double(symsum(2^n, n, 0, k-1)));
   disp(folds);
end
```

and `disp` it, just to check,but I get error 
 `Undefined function 'dragonCurve' for input arguments of type 'double'`
Does anyone know why is this happening, and btw I'm not sure how to do 1st line of my M-file when there are no output arguments. Should I put output argument, even if I'm not going to use it, like `function y = dragonCurve(k)` or just omit it?

Comment: You do not need the output argument.  By chance, when you evaluated at the command line, was k already defined?  In order to pre-allocate, matlab has to be able to evaluate the second argument of `zeros` to an integer.

Comment: k is input argument. Shouldn't it be defined just by calling it out in input args ?
But anyways, I just replaced it with t like:
function dragonCurve(t)
k = t;
and than the rest is same, but im still getting the same error.

Comment: "Undefined function 'dragonCurve' for input arguments of type 'double'" means that `dragonCurve` is not in your [present working directory](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pwd.html) or on your [path](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html).

Comment: That solved it... Spent 2 hours googling for solution. Thanks !